# How to align text with image in html/css

Tags: html, css

I have an image and some text. I currently have the text and image center, however I want the contents class to be on the right hand side of the image (vertically aligned). I have tried vertical align but it does not seem too work. Could someone help me please?

[where I want text to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdUQZ.png)

https://jsfiddle.net/skriker11/3t7asmhf/1/

```css
.card{
  border: solid red;
  text-align: center;
}

img{
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.card > .content h3, p {
  margin: 0;
} 

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="card">

      <h1>Title of widget</h1>

      <div class='content'>
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech" width='100' height=100/>
        <p>Sydney</p>
        <h3>26</h3>
        <p><strong>Wind</strong></p> <p>NE 24km/h</p>
      </div>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How about wrapping all the other elements except img in div.content with div? Then div.content's flex-direction should be row, while the new div's flex-direction should be column.

Comment: maybe this will answer your question [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you could do, mind the comments with `FIX`:

```css
.card{
  border: solid red;
  
  /* FIX: make the card as flexbox with direction of column */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

img{
  border: 1px solid red;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.card > .content h3, p {
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  /* FIX#2: flexbox with direction of row */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <h1>Title of widget</h1>
  
  <div class='content'>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech" width='100' height=100/>

    <!-- FIX: wrap all texts in a div -->
    <div class="description">
      <p>Sydney</p>
      <h3>26</h3>
      <p><strong>Wind</strong></p> <p>NE 24km/h</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks, so I want the description vertically aligned to the middle of the text, sorry if I weren't clear. I'll show you what I mean, I just updated the question

Comment: @tjStack I just updated the answer, is this what you want?

Comment: Amazing. Thank you.